# Spock tests not running after switching to 1.3-groovy-2.5 instead a Nullpointer in ASTTransformation

Tags: java, maven, testing, groovy, spock

## Issue description

I wrote tests for Java8 code (Spring controllers) with using  1.3-groovy-2.4 version of spock-core and spock-spring and everything was fine.

Now we are changing towards to Java11 / groovy 2.5. So I tried using  1.3-groovy-2.5 but even for minimal tests I get the following error 
message.

`Error:Groovyc: While compiling tests of groovy2.5.spock: Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.3-groovy-2.5/spock-core-1.3-groovy-2.5.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.NullPointerException`

`Warning:Groovyc: While compiling tests of groovy2.5.spock: The global transform for class groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation is defined in both jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.11/groovy-2.4.11-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation and jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.5/groovy-2.5.5.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation - the former definition will be used and the latter ignored.`

`Warning:Groovyc: While compiling tests of groovy2.5.spock: The global transform for class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation is defined in both jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.11/groovy-2.4.11-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation and jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.5/groovy-2.5.5.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation - the former definition will be used and the latter ignored.`

## Additional Environment information

IDE IntelliJ 2019.2

### Java/JDK

jdk1.8.0_152

### Groovy version

Groovy Version: 2.5.3 JVM: 11.0.2 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

### Build tool version

#### Apache Maven

Apache Maven 3.5.4

### Operating System

Mac 10.14 Mojave

### IDE

IntelliJ 2019.2

### Build-tool dependencies used

#### Apache Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-groovy</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Possible Reason

The gremlin-groovy 3.3.1 has as a groovy 2.4.11 dependency this produces the conflict that causes the error.

Comment: Have you verified, that you are using groovy 2.5.+ in your _maven_ deps?  The version you are showing there is some installed one on your system? Older Springboot versions pin Groovy to 2.4

Comment: Please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. There are too many possible problem sources here. You might remember it helped me answer your other question a while ago. ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex I am struggling to reproduce the error in an MCVE, that's why I first asked if anybody has also encountered this error. 

I have copied my entire pom.xml into a new project but I don't get the error there. That is where I am stuck. I am not allowed to  post the code where the error occurs.

Comment: I found the reason and added it to the question, I made an error creating a new project to test the problem that's why I could not reproduce it in the beginning.

Comment: See? This is why I was asking for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How can anyone know you are using Gremlin if don't even so much as mention it in the original question? By trying to create an MCVE in order to reproduce the problem, you already found the root cause, which BTW is part of an MCVE's value as a problem solving tool. P.S.: There still is no MCVE in your updated question now, just a small Maven POM fragment and not a single line of application or test code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I don't have time to write an MCVE at the moment. Finding out that the gremlin dependency is the likely reason is enought for me rightnow. The lib with this dependency will also move to Java11 / Groovy 2.5 so I am waiting till this happens and will continue than.

Comment: No need to wait. As you can easily verify at [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tinkerpop/gremlin-groovy), version 3.3.x indeed has a Groovy 2.4.x dependency - even though it would be worth a try to override it via Maven. But that is not even necessary because gremlin-groovy 3.4.x has already upgraded to Groovy 2.5. The latest version [3.4.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tinkerpop/gremlin-groovy/3.4.3) e.g. depends on Groovy 2.5.7, but probably won't complain about another 2.5.x such as the latest 2.5.8 either.